# how to call user defined jquery function from ajax loaded page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have 2 pages

- index.php
- login.php

From the index.php make a ajax call and get the login.php

index.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("a").click(function(e) {
                var model= $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('href'),
                    cache:false,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType:"json"
                });
                model.done(function(data){
                    $("#body").html(data.bodyy);
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });     
                $("form").submit(function(e) {
                            alert("Triggered");
                });
        });

    </script>



    <body>
    <div id="body"><a href="login.php">Login</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the ajax page: login.php

```
<?php
    $body='<form class="form-signin" action="#" method="post" id="login">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="username" name="username">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
        <table><th>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button> </th><th width="5%">
        <h3>  or  </h3></th><th>
         <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="./registration.php" >Register</a></th></table>
      </form>
      <script>
        </script>
';
    $data= array(
        'bodyy' => $body,
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

when i submit login form the `$("form").submit(function(e)` not called.
i get this problem when i call this from ajax loaded page

Comment: If you are trying to display a login form when the user clicks the Login link; you might be better served to create the form part and simply hide it with CSS and then reveal it on click using event handlers.  Then you could focus on using AJAX to perform the actual login validation(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is becuase you are binding to forms at the time the jQuery is executed. For "delayed" event binding (meaning you want to bind to **all** forms and not just the ones on the page at the time you do the binding) you must bind to a parent element, and then specify a child selector to fire the handler for, such as:

```
$("body").on("click", "form", function(e) {});
```

This will bind the click on body, but only fire the handler when a form that is a child of body is clicked (using more specific parent elements can be beneficial if you have forms in the body that should not do this action).

When binding events in jQuery, make sure that you are only binding to elements that are present on the page when you perform the bind otherwise it will break the event binding. Side note, should you need to "move" elements around without breaking their bound events you should use jQuery's `detach` function instead of `remove`. The `detach` function removes the element from the page but keeps the event binding information for it allowing you to place it elsewhere without updating event functions (or handling disposing of references).